# .each function when try to load content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this to add colors to spans:

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  var color = $(this).data('c');
  $(this).css('background', color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cor" data-c="red"></span>
```

It works well if the content is loading direct. But if I load the content using jQuery it will not run. any ideas?

Comment: It work for me, what you mean about "if i load the content"?

Comment: when a jquery call this page, it won't run the code. but if I open the page on the browser it works. @alvarofvr I'd like to run this code using something like `$( document ).on( "LOADING", "span", function() {`

Comment: extract method from this code and call the method after content loads using jquery

Comment: @K1laba could you give me an example?

Comment: here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/38Lupc7t/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('span.cor').each(function() {
   var color = $(this).data('c');
   $(this).css('background', color);
  });
});
```